# How can I give ascending numbers to rows in a data frame by value

Tags: r, dataframe, dplyr, tidyverse

I have a data frame similar to this:

```
[a][b][c]    
1 xxx a
2 xxx a
3 xxx a
4 xxx a
5 xxx b
6 xxx b
7 xxx c
8 xxx c
```

What I need to do is to create a new column with ascending numbers. But the numbers have to go back to 1 for every unique value of [c]. I'm looking for something like this:

```
[a][b][c]    
1 xxx a 1
2 xxx a 2
3 xxx a 3
4 xxx a 4
5 xxx b 1
6 xxx b 2
7 xxx c 1
8 xxx c 2
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The package `dplyr` from `tidyverse` can help. With `n()` function you can create the index you want. Try this:

```
library(tidyverse)
#Data
df <- data.frame(var1=rep(c('a','b'),4),stringsAsFactors = F)
#Mutate
df %>% arrange(var1) %>% group_by_all() %>% mutate(var2=1:n())
```

Output:

```
# A tibble: 8 x 2
# Groups:   var1 [2]
  var1   var2
  <chr> <int>
1 a         1
2 a         2
3 a         3
4 a         4
5 b         1
6 b         2
7 b         3
8 b         4
```

Comment: I should have been more clear: I have 57 different unique variables in my df so I can't assign them by hand.

Comment: @NicoSaameli And you wanna group by all those variables?

Comment: Exactly. We're speaking of filenames in 57 different folders that I have listed in a df. I want every file to have an ascending number. The best case would be if they all start at 3 =).

Comment: @NicoSaameli You could try `df %>% group_by_all() %>% mutate(var2=1:n())`. Let me know if that works for you!

Comment: It actually did. Thx a lot!